# Trying to get value of hidden field using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to a value from a hidden field.

Here is the HTML which is spit out by a Visualforce page (Salesforce) (The ids are dynamically generated )

```
<div style="width:300px;position:relative" id="massConvertwithInputs:pbmconvertInput:pbformmconvertInput:pbsmconvertInput:pbspbtable:0:optableAccount">
<!--  Need value for below field to be alerted -->
<input type="hidden" value="001i0000008LDtv" id="massConvertwithInputs:pbmconvertInput:pbformmconvertInput:pbsmconvertInput:pbspbtable:0:accountLookup_lkid" name="massConvertwithInputs:pbmconvertInput:pbformmconvertInput:pbsmconvertInput:pbspbtable:0:accountLookup_lkid">
<input type="hidden" value="Aethna Home Products" id="massConvertwithInputs:pbmconvertInput:pbformmconvertInput:pbsmconvertInput:pbspbtable:0:accountLookup_lkold" name="massConvertwithInputs:pbmconvertInput:pbformmconvertInput:pbsmconvertInput:pbspbtable:0:accountLookup_lkold">
<input type="hidden" value="001" id="massConvertwithInputs:pbmconvertInput:pbformmconvertInput:pbsmconvertInput:pbspbtable:0:accountLookup_lktp" name="massConvertwithInputs:pbmconvertInput:pbformmconvertInput:pbsmconvertInput:pbspbtable:0:accountLookup_lktp">
<input type="hidden" value="0" id="massConvertwithInputs:pbmconvertInput:pbformmconvertInput:pbsmconvertInput:pbspbtable:0:accountLookup_lspf" name="massConvertwithInputs:pbmconvertInput:pbformmconvertInput:pbsmconvertInput:pbspbtable:0:accountLookup_lspf">
<input type="hidden" value="0" id="massConvertwithInputs:pbmconvertInput:pbformmconvertInput:pbsmconvertInput:pbspbtable:0:accountLookup_lspfsub" name="massConvertwithInputs:pbmconvertInput:pbformmconvertInput:pbsmconvertInput:pbspbtable:0:accountLookup_lspfsub">
<input type="hidden" value="1" id="massConvertwithInputs:pbmconvertInput:pbformmconvertInput:pbsmconvertInput:pbspbtable:0:accountLookup_mod" name="massConvertwithInputs:pbmconvertInput:pbformmconvertInput:pbsmconvertInput:pbspbtable:0:accountLookup_mod"><span class="lookupInput">
<!-- I do get the value of below field -->
<input type="text" size="20" onchange="getElementByIdCS('massConvertwithInputs:pbmconvertInput:pbformmconvertInput:pbsmconvertInput:pbspbtable:0:accountLookup_lkid').value='';getElementByIdCS('massConvertwithInputs:pbmconvertInput:pbformmconvertInput:pbsmconvertInput:pbspbtable:0:accountLookup_mod').value='1';" name="massConvertwithInputs:pbmconvertInput:pbformmconvertInput:pbsmconvertInput:pbspbtable:0:accountLookup" maxlength="255" id="massConvertwithInputs:pbmconvertInput:pbformmconvertInput:pbsmconvertInput:pbspbtable:0:accountLookup">
<script>new ForeignKeyInputElement("massConvertwithInputs:pbmconvertInput:pbformmconvertInput:pbsmconvertInput:pbspbtable:0:accountLookup","/_ui/common/data/LookupValidationServlet",null,true,{"acent":"001"});</script><a title="Account Name Lookup (New Window)" onclick="setLastMousePosition(event)" id="massConvertwithInputs:pbmconvertInput:pbformmconvertInput:pbsmconvertInput:pbspbtable:0:accountLookup_lkwgt" href="javascript:%20openLookup%28%27%2F_ui%2Fcommon%2Fdata%2FLookupPage%3Flkfm%3DmassConvertwithInputs%253ApbmconvertInput%253ApbformmconvertInput%26lknm%3DmassConvertwithInputs%253ApbmconvertInput%253ApbformmconvertInput%253ApbsmconvertInput%253Apbspbtable%253A0%253AaccountLookup%26lktp%3D%27%20%2B%20getElementByIdCS%28%27massConvertwithInputs%3ApbmconvertInput%3ApbformmconvertInput%3ApbsmconvertInput%3Apbspbtable%3A0%3AaccountLookup_lktp%27%29.value%2C670%2C%271%27%2C%27%26lksrch%3D%27%20%2B%20escapeUTF%28getElementByIdCS%28%27massConvertwithInputs%3ApbmconvertInput%3ApbformmconvertInput%3ApbsmconvertInput%3Apbspbtable%3A0%3AaccountLookup%27%29.value.substring%280%2C%2080%29%29%29"><img title="Account Name Lookup (New Window)" onmouseover="this.className = 'lookupIconOn';this.className = 'lookupIconOn';" onmouseout="this.className = 'lookupIcon';this.className = 'lookupIcon';" onfocus="this.className = 'lookupIconOn';" onblur="this.className = 'lookupIcon';" class="lookupIcon" alt="Account Name Lookup (New Window)" src="/s.gif"></a></span><select style="width:148px" size="1" class="accSelectandlookup" name="massConvertwithInputs:pbmconvertInput:pbformmconvertInput:pbsmconvertInput:pbspbtable:0:convertedStatus" id="massConvertwithInputs:pbmconvertInput:pbformmconvertInput:pbsmconvertInput:pbspbtable:0:convertedStatus">  <option value="000000000000000000">Create New Account: Greenwich Media</option>
</select></div>
```

Here is jquery code i am using the alert the values

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {

$('form :input[id$="accountLookup"]').change(function() {
     $('form :input[id$="accountLookup"]').each(function () {
            var str= $(this).attr("id") + "_lkid"; 
            alert($(str).val());// This alert shows undefined
            alert($(this).val());// This shows the Aethna Home Products which correct
            alert($('massConvertwithInputs:pbmconvertInput:pbformmconvertInput:pbsmconvertInput:pbspbtable:0:accountLookup_lkid').val());  // This shows undefined
});  
}); 
$('form :input[id$="accountLookup"]').change(function() {
     $('form :input[id$="accountLookup_lkid"]').each(function () {
            alert($(this).val());  // This shows a blank value
});  
}); 
});   


</script>
```

I need to get the value of the field `massConvertwithInputs:pbmconvertInput:pbformmconvertInput:pbsmconvertInput:pbspbtable:0:accountLookup_lkid`

I have commented the jquery script with what each alert is throwing currently

Any idea what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed the # in your selector :

```
alert($("#massConvertwithInputs:pbmconvertInput:pbformmconvertInput:pbsmconvertInput:pbspbtable:0:accountLookup_lkid").val());
```

Same here

```
var str= '#' + $(this).attr("id") + "_lkid"; 
alert($(str).val());
```

Comment: Thanks @RafH, but adding # throws me this error on the console uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: pbmconvertInput

Comment: The problem is the naming of your ids, : is used by jQuery  (for example :visible to get elements that are visible).

Comment: is there a way we could get around this. I dont have control on how the ids are spit out

Comment: You can replace the : in ids by something else : http://jsfiddle.net/yiernehr/3Xeaa/

Comment: I tried doing this a little differently. Looks to me building the str and doing a alert of alert($(str).val()); is throwing undefined. check this http://jsfiddle.net/prady/pcVPd/

Comment: Finally, renaming ids is not needed, you can get/set all the values you want by using only the string that is at the end of generated ids and the $= jQuery operator. http://jsfiddle.net/yiernehr/pcVPd/12/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use  `#` when you are using id as selector.If it is class then use `.`  as selector

```
$('massConvertwithInputs:pbmconvertInput:pbformmconvertInput:pbsmconvertInput:pbspbtable:0:accountLookup_lkid').val()
```

with

```
$('#massConvertwithInputs:pbmconvertInput:pbformmconvertInput:pbsmconvertInput:pbspbtable:0:accountLookup_lkid').val()
```

Comment: thanks @PSR, but adding # throws me this error on the console uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: pbmconvertInput

Comment: I think somewhere you are getting exception